# How to allow Siri to call only specific persons

Tags: contacts, siri, call

I use Siri to call some fixed persons(e.g. family), but sometimes Siri calls to wrong person. I don't need to call with Siri for other people.
Is it possible to create whitelist or blacklist to call with Siri?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such an option for Siri.

But you can adjust Siri to call your "Mom" by sayin "call my mom" and Siri will ask who is your mom from contacts then you can set the name of mom.
Uncle, brother, sister, dad and etc. can be learned by Siri also.